# dispatch_once vs runtime check for once initialized property

Tags: objective-c, initialization, grand-central-dispatch

What is the difference between `dispatch_once` and using runtime conditional check for the property that requires only once initialization

Method 1: runtime checking

```
- (MyProp *)myProp{
  if (!_myProp){
    _myProp = [[MyProp alloc] init];
  }
  return _myProp;
}
```

Method 2: use `dispatch_once`

```
- (MyProp *)myProp{
  dispatch_once_t once;
  dispatch_once(&once, ^{
    _myProp = [[MyProp alloc] init];
  }
  return _myProp;
}
```

I guess that method 2 is somehow faster but not really sure.

Could anyone give me any deal?

Thanks

Comment: lets assume that i never do it

Answer (score 1):

`dispatch_once` is thread safe. So if two threads call `myProp` for the first time simultaneously, `dispatch_once` ensures only one initializes the variable. Method 1 may initialize the variable twice, and could even corrupt memory such that the reference is invalid. Once the property has been initialized, these behave identically.

Method 2 is actually slightly slower than Method 1, particularly during the first initialization. But in the usual case (reading after initialization), it is *extremely* close (possibly identical) in performance. If you want a much more in-depth exploration of how it works and why, see Mike Ash's [Secrets of dispatch_once](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2014-06-06-secrets-of-dispatch_once.html).

Note that your Method 2 code is incorrect. You've made `once` an automatic local variable. It needs to be `static` or `dispatch_once` can't do its job. What you meant was:

```
- (MyProp *)myProp{
  static dispatch_once_t once; // <--- this "static" is critical
  dispatch_once(&once, ^{
    _myProp = [[MyProp alloc] init];
  }
  return _myProp;
}
```